# How to improve this Needleman-Wunsch implementation in C#?

Tags: c#, algorithm, bioinformatics

I split my implementation of this sequence alignment algorithm in three methods. Where NeedlemanWunsch-method makes use of the ScoringFunction and the Traceback methods. Further I decided to go with two matices. One matrix is for the scoring, the second contains data to make the traceback easier.

```
public static int ScoreFunction(char a,char b,int matchScore,int mismatchScore) 
            {
                if (a == b)
                {
                    return matchScore;
                }
                else 
                {
                    return mismatchScore;
                }
            }

public static string[] NeedlemanWunsch(string sequenceA, string sequenceB, int gapPenalty, int matchScore, int mismatchScore)
                {

                #region Initialize
                int[,] matrix = new int[sequenceA.Length + 1, sequenceB.Length + 1];
                char[,] tracebackMatrix = new char[sequenceA.Length + 1, sequenceB.Length + 1];
                matrix[0, 0] = 0;

                for (int i = 1; i < sequenceA.Length + 1;i++)
                {
                    matrix[i,0] = matrix[i-1,0] + gapPenalty;
                    tracebackMatrix[i,0] = 'L';
                }

                for (int i = 1; i < sequenceB.Length + 1; i++)
                {
                    matrix[0, i] = matrix[0 , i - 1] + gapPenalty;
                    tracebackMatrix[0,i] = 'U';
                }
                #endregion

                #region Scoring
                for (int i = 1; i < sequenceA.Length + 1;i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 1; j < sequenceB.Length + 1;j++)
                    {
                        int diagonal = matrix[i - 1, j - 1] + ScoreFunction(sequenceA[i-1],sequenceB[j-1],matchScore,mismatchScore);
                        int links = matrix[i - 1, j] + gapPenalty;
                        int oben = matrix[i, j - 1] + gapPenalty;
                        matrix[i, j] = Math.Max(oben,Math.Max(links, diagonal));                           

                        if(matrix[i,j] == diagonal)
                        {
                            tracebackMatrix[i, j] = 'D';
                        }
                        else if (matrix[i, j] == links)
                        {
                            tracebackMatrix[i, j] = 'L';
                        }
                        else if (matrix[i, j] == oben)
                        {
                            tracebackMatrix[i, j] = 'U';
                        }
                    }
                }
                #endregion

                #region Traceback
                return TraceBack(tracebackMatrix,sequenceA,sequenceB);
                #endregion

            }

public static string[] TraceBack(char[,] tracebackMatrix,string sequenzA, string sequenzB) 
        {

            int i = tracebackMatrix.GetLength(0) - 1;
            int j = tracebackMatrix.GetLength(1) - 1;

            string alignedSeqA = "";
            string alignedSeqB = "";


            while(i != 0 && j != 0)
            {
                switch (tracebackMatrix[i, j])
                {
                    case 'D':
                        alignedSeqA += sequenzA[i - 1];
                        alignedSeqB += sequenzB[j - 1];                        
                        i--;
                        j--;
                        break;
                    case 'U':                        
                        alignedSeqA += "-";
                        alignedSeqB += sequenzB[j - 1];
                        j--;
                        break;
                    case 'L':
                        alignedSeqA += sequenzA[i - 1];
                        alignedSeqB += "-";
                        i--;
                        break;

                }
            }

        string[] alignments = new string[2];

        alignedSeqA = new string(alignedSeqA.Reverse().ToArray());
        alignedSeqB = new string(alignedSeqB.Reverse().ToArray());
        alignments[0] = alignedSeqA;
        alignments[1] = alignedSeqB;

        return alignments;

    }
```

I am especially concerned about the traceback method and whether it is a good idea to use two matrices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some general notes:

- The TraceBack method does string concatenation in a tight loop. This is a big f***ing nono. Use a [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead, and you will notice a considerable speedup. You have to understand that .net Strings are **immutable**. This means that a statement like `strA += strB` does not *update* `strA`, it creates a third string and updates the reference to `strA`. This means concatenation in a tight loop is *very* expansive.
- If you do not have a compelling reason to use 2d Arrays (`var bla = new int[5,5]`), use jagged arrays (`var bla = new int[5][5]`). Most of the time, the .net JIT compiler can drop the bounds checks for jagged arrays, but not for 2D arrays.
- It may be worthwhile to convert tracebackMatrix from chars (16 bits) to bytes (8 bits)

Comment: All three points make sense to me. But I don't really understand how the StringBuilder would change the method. That wouldn't make the while-loop unnecessary, would it? Or should I just replace the concatenation "" += "" by a call to a StringBuilder method?

Comment: I've edited the description but yes, you would replace ``strA += strB`` with ``strBuilderA.Append(strB)`` and at the end you would add a single statement like ``result = strBuilderA.ToString()``

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your method "TraceBack" does not return anything (what should it return, both strings?). You can also simplify your first method to use this instead:

```
public static int ScoreFunction(char a, char b, int matchScore, int mismatchScore)
{
    return a == b ? matchScore : mismatchScore;
}
```

Rest does not look bad to me, however, I am not that familiar with the algorithm...

Comment: I somehow missed to copy/paste the return statement into the function. So edit is done.